# javascript synch audio & video html5 controls on pause

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on video playback in a browser window with the video source and audio source being retrieved from a backend dataserver. The playback works and is in synch when starting playback and if it is paused and started up again. The issue I am having is when dragging the control back on video. It does not go back to the specific frame automatically. Is there a way to control this in the javascript?

The other issue is that the video control dictates playback of the audio. Meaning if you play the video the audio  begins but not vice versa. Just looking for suggestions on how to handle these kind of issues.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("wVideo");
var aud = document.getElementById("wAudio");
var playbackURL = "not yet set";
var selectedID;
var selectedType;

vid.onplay = function() {

  try {
    aud.play();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error on PlaySelectedCall: " + e.message + ".(punt)");
  }
}

vid.onpause = function() {
  try {
    aud.pause();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error on pause: " + err.message);
  }
}

vid.onseeking = function() {

  if (vid.currentTime == 0) {
    aud.currentTime = 0;
    aud.pause();
  }
}


function exportVideo() {
  var exportScreenURL = "/myplayer/exportSaveCall.action?type=screen";
  var frame = document.getElementById("playScreenFrameII");
  frame.src = exportScreenURL;
}

function playScreen() {
  var playScreenForm = document.getElementById('playScreenForm');
  playScreenForm.action = "/myplayer/exportSaveCall.action?type=screen";
  document.getElementById('callID').value = getSelectedID();
  playScreenForm.submit();
  hide();
}

function showButtonOnStart() {
  var x = document.getElementById('buttonLink');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

function getAudioTicket() {

  showButtonOnStart();
  selectedID = getSelectedID();
  console.log("selectedID is " + selectedID);
  if (selectedID == null) {
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
      url: "/myplayer/getAudio.action",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        ID: selectedID
      },
      success: function(result, status, responseText) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(result);
        try {
          playbackURL = data.playbackURL;
          if (playbackURL != null) {
            console.log("Audio url is " + playbackURL);
            aud.setAttribute("src", playbackURL);
            aud.preload = "auto";

          } else {
            console.log("No audio found for this");
            aud.style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
        } catch (err) {

          writeAjaxError("setupTicketedPlaybackURL()", err.message);
        }

      },
      error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        writeAjaxError("ScreenplayerWMP  
          setupTicketedPlaybackURL()
          ",errorThrown);
        }
      });


  }
```

```html
<body style="width:100%; height:100%; background:buttonface;" bottommargin="0" id="body" language="javascript" onload="getAudio();" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0">
  <!-- Media Player -->
  <div>
    <center>
      <video width="100%" height="90%" id="wVideo" controls controlsList="nodownload" preload="auto" autoplay>
   <source src="${playbackURL}" type="video/webm">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>

      <audio controls id="wAudio" controls controlsList="nodownload 
      noremoteplayback" preload="auto" autoplay>
  <source src="" type="audio/wav" >
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
    </center>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any chance your backend can just encode a video file with the audio included within it? That would be better than having separate controls for both.

Comment: That would be ideal but not at option for me at this point. I did some research and it seems trying to seek the video in that particular pop up window if you are using chrome, is problematic. If the video is downloaded completely first, then you can seek but of course the audio control is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try listening to the `timeupdate` event on both your `audio` and `video` elements, which updates when the `currentTime` changes which might make synching easier. I haven't tried it, but it might help things.

Comment: I just realized that the best option for me is to first fix the inability of the video control to seek back to a previous frame. This is chrome specific

Comment: Just another comment; the way firefox and edge handles the playback over chrome is far better. Because chrome does not fully download the stream first, the seek back capability is lost.